# mostrar datos en tabla con laravel 9 y vuejs 3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue3, laravel-9

Estoy tratando de crear un componente que renderice una tabla con los datos de mi DB. Para ello estoy usando Laravel 9 y vuejs 3.

Estoy empezando con vuejs 3, me defendia bastante con la versión 2, pero por lo que estoy viendo ha cambiado mucho la manera de trabajar.

He estado siguiendo un manual y tengo estructurados mis modulos de vue con `composables` `componentes` y los archivos de configuracion.

lo unico que pretendo hacer es llenar el tbody con mis datos de API.

Este es mi composable con mi ruta, uso las rutas de Laravel, no uso vue router.

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios';

export default function useCompanies(){
    const companies = ref([])

    const getCompanies = async () => {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/companies')
        companies.value = response.data
    }
    
    return{
        companies,
        getCompanies
    } 
}
```

En mi composable, como se puede ver unicamente tengo mi funcion que retorna los datos.

Mi componente:

```
<template>
    <div class="tabla offset-md-1">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>PRICE</th>
                    <th>EDIT</th>
                    <th>REMOVE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{ companies }}
                <template v-for="item in companies" :key="item.id">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="alert alert-success d-none" role="alert" id="correcto"></div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert" id="error"></div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import useCompanies from "../../js/composables/Treatments"
    import { onMounted } from 'vue'
    
    export default {
        setup() {
            const { companies, getCompanies } = useCompanies()

            onMounted(getCompanies)

            return {
                companies,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Importo mi compsable y llamo a mi función. Hago el html y el v-for, pero mi array de datos en el template está vacio. Sin embargo en mi console.log()

[image: resultado de console]

En mi controlador de API:

```
public function index()
    {
        return CompanyResource::collection(Company::all());
    }
```

y el `Company::Resource`

```
class CompanyResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Mi ruta API

```
Route::apiResource('companies', CompanyController::class);
```

Mi ruta devuelve:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"nif":"dddd","name":"dddd","address":"dddd","location":"dddd","province":"dddd","postal_code":222,"phone1":222,"fax1":222,"phone2":222,"fax2":222,"observations":"eeee","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]}
```

Alguien me puede orientar en que estoy haciendo mal¿?

Answer (score 0):

No veo ningún error en el código que has presentado.

Lo más seguro es que sea un error en el *loop* que estas generando en el template.

Por lo general en la documentación de VueJS los *loops* debe de estar acompañados de un `:key` tal y como has hecho, pero al estar declarando ese `:key` en un `<template>` es posible que te este dando ese problema.

Mi recomendación es que lo cambies a lo siguiente y pruebes si sigue fallando:

```
<tbody>
 <template v-for="item in companies">
   <tr :key="item.id">
     <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
   </tr>
 </template>
</tbody>
```